# How do I attach 2 objects if one has been appended from another scene?

Tags: mesh, snapping, outliner

I am working on a character and I made the hands for it in another file. I appended it to the file containing the character. I am trying to attach the two together, but they are 2 separate objects in the outliner.

[image: The hand and the body]

[image: What the outliner says]

I am trying to snap the 2 objects together similar as how it is done in the  [video here at 12:38](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAO4C_8y0w8&t=617s)

The body has the mirror modifier applied if that means anything.

Thank you.

Comment: I may have misunderstood, but I think all you need to do is to combine the objects (select both, press ctrl-j) then adjust the position of the hand to match the arm. They probably won't snap together easily, but if you adjust the hand to match the arm, you can then use Mesh/CleanUp/Merge By Distance to merge the two once you've got the vertices close to matching.

Comment: Never mind the problem I had with the mirror modifier, I fixed that. Thanks for the tip.